# Unable to copy current flask request context to multiple gevent threads

Tags: python, flask, gevent

I am trying to copy Flask's current request context into gevent threads so that I can use the original request context inside those threds for logging.

I referred below link.
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.copy_current_request_context

using the decorator `@copy_current_request_context` works fine when I spawn only 1 gevent thread. But if I spawn multiple threads, below exceptions are raised. It seems each thread pops a wrong context from the stack which other thread has pushed.

```
AssertionError: Popped wrong app context.  (<flask.ctx.AppContext object at 0x7f57983b7ba8> instead of <flask.ctx.AppContext object at 0x7f57983be9b0>
```

Here is the sample code what I am trying to do:

```
def index(items):
    @copy_current_request_context
    def do_some_work(item):
        # do some work

    threads = [gevent.spawn(do_some_work, item) for item in items]
    gevent.joinall(threads)
```

Any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
top = flask.globals._request_ctx_stack.top
# copy the request context
reqctx = top.copy()
def do_some_work(item):
    # Here the context stack is not the same as above, since do_some_work
    # is called in a greenlet, the stack returned is empty. 
    flask.globals._request_ctx_stack.push(reqctx)

    # ----------- do your work here -----------------


    flask.globals._request_ctx_stack.pop() # very important to do this, or your memory will explose 

threads = [gevent.spawn(do_some_work, item) for item in items]
```

A better version is to put the 'push' and 'pop' actions into a context manager, i'll let you do this